# CUDA on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda, 23.04

Installed Ubuntu 23.04 (because it worked with my RTX 4090 out of the box, after problems with 22.04). Now I want to install CUDA.

I followed this guide- [CUDA preinstallation steps](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#pre-installation-actions)

I installed the Cuda toolkit for 23.04 from here [UbuntuUpdates](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/lunar/multiverse/base/nvidia-cuda-toolkit)

with the APT INSTALL.

Now I want to follow the  [installation guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#ubuntu), but my distro is not listed.

Is there a way to get it on 23.04?

Comment: You'd be better off following one of the answers on this site, like 1077061.  Basically, get your system running with the video driver offered in the standard repositories, then use the Nvidia .run script,to reject any video driver offers, and select the lib/bin locations as the cuda install's bin and lib, not the system areas. CUDA's just an app, don't let it take over your system or various update problems (kernel, video driver,...) will occur.

Comment: @ubfan1 Your comment pointed me in the right direction. I just realized, for running pytorch with cuda I don't need more (`torch.cuda.device_count()` returns `1`). When installing 23.04 the nvidia drivers where already installed (opted for 3rd party drivers). But looking through the answers you were referring, they all need a distro specific repo, and for 23.04 there is none.

Comment: In the past, when running a system later than the Nvidia download, I always had good luck just using the latest one (that your hardware supports, but you have no such problem with a 4090). U23.04 may default to a later compiler, but the earlier ones are still available in the standard repos. Do NOT change your system default compiler! Install what's needed, then use the CUDA setup to select the gcc-? needed (links or even putting executables into cuda/bin).

Comment: @nanuuq Did you ever find an answer? Or did you have to downgrade to 22.04 LTS? (4070 did not work out the box for me on 23.04 anyway.)

Comment: @sodiumnitrate I got it running with 23.04, but every OS update I had to fix something. Most of the time it was sufficient to repair broken packages. But with the last update, it did not, so now I am trying to install 22.04. But that is another pain, because on my large screen the safe graphics installer only lets me choose 800x600 resolution and it is impossible to install that way. Here 23.04 was good. All worked good.

Comment: @nanuuq yeah I'm now scared to upgrade to 23.10, as 23.04 has like two months of support left. Not sure if I should have gone with LTS...

Comment: @sodiumnitrate That's what I ended up doing, upgrading to 23.10. Since I found no way of installing 22.04 because of resolution issues (could not see the buttons and input fields due to 800x600 resulution) I tried upgrade to 23.10. That solved my recently broken Ubuntu installation. Now it boots like a charm, Nvidia is working, all good.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me. I already had nvidia drivers installed (version `535.104.12`) The latest cuda toolkit (for 22.04) seems to require/ship with `535.104.05`. I had to purge/uninstall all nvidia drivers and libraries. Upon reboot, nouveau didn't recognize my 4070 card, so I booted into recovery, opened command prompt as root, and installed it with the runfile. Rebooted again, added cuda home to path, and blacklisted nouveau.

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment. I had a working 23.04, but with each update/upgrade I had to fix something. Do you think, blacklisting nouveau would help here?

Comment: @nanuuq My understanding is that blacklisting nouveau wasn't necessary for successfully installing the cuda toolkit. I just needed to do it because otherwise I had no graphics.